# Find the transformation to convert to unit square

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find a transformation $G: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the curved parallelogram bounded by $y = 3x - 4, 3x, 1/2x, 1/2(x + 4)$ onto unit square in $uv$ plane.

So we want $(u, v) = F(x, y)$.

I see a point of intersection was $(12/5, 16/5)$ and this must map to $(1, 1)$

Other points were

$(4/5, 12/5), (8/5, 4/5), (0, 0)$

But how in general do I find the transformation?

Comment: Do a screen snip of Desmos https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1gd4jcdlas  and include it in your question ... oh you don't have enough points to do that ... shall I do it for you ?

Comment: I am not sure about your points of intersection ?

Answer (score 2):

First, we must point out the OP misconstrued $y=1/2x$ as $\frac{1}{2x}$ and $1/2(x+4)$ as $\frac{1}{2(x+4)}$.

We wish to find the linear transformation which maps the parallelogram bounded by the following four straight lines onto the unit square in the $uv$ plane.

1. $y=3x-4$
2. $y=3x$
3. $y=\frac{1}{2}x$
4. $y=\frac{1}{2}(x+4)$

[image: parallelogram]

Thus we wish to find a linear transformation achieving the following transformations

1. $\left(\frac{4}{5},\frac{12}{5}\right)\rightarrow (0,1)$
2. $\left(\frac{12}{5},\frac{16}{5}\right)\rightarrow (1,1)$
3. $\left(0,0\right)\rightarrow (0,0)$
4. $\left(\frac{8}{5},\frac{4}{5}\right)\rightarrow (1,0)$

So we need to find constants $a,b,c,d$ satisfying

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{4}{5}a+\frac{12}{5}b=0\\
\frac{12}{5}a+\frac{16}{5}b=1\\
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{4}{5}c+\frac{12}{5}d=1\\
\frac{12}{5}c+\frac{16}{5}d=1\\
\end{eqnarray}

Which are found to be $a=\frac{3}{4},b=-\frac{1}{4},c=-\frac{1}{4},d=\frac{1}{2}$

Thus the transformation sought is

\begin{eqnarray}
u&=&\phantom{...}\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{1}{4}y\\
v&=&-\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{1}{2}y
\end{eqnarray}

It is readily verified that this moves the four vertices of the parallelogram to the four corresponding vertices of the unit square.